# Fix Terraria Choppy Lag Slowness During Single Player on macOS OS X

Tags: terraria

[See here](https://media.giphy.com/media/lpOwvi6TKKYco/giphy.gif) for a GIF showing the behavior.

I'm on a brand new world, brand new character, on macOS Sierra 10.12.2.

When I try to walk around, the game is **completely** unplayable because the game freezes about twice a second just when I walk around. I have tried disabling every single option in the settings, tried shrinking the window really small, tried going full screen, EVERYTHING. Has anybody else seen this issue?

Comment: The official Terraria steam page only lists up to El Capitan, 10.11.6. There's no mention of Sierra, so there may be some incompatibility there.